# How to read value entered in input text box in ARIA-LABEL?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, uiaccessibility

I want to specify an ARIA-LABEL before a text box which reads the value inside the text box. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `aria-label` is used on interactive elements (not before or after them). On a text box, it's designed to specify the alternative text replacement for the label, not for the inner text. The inner text is natively spoken out by the screen reader.

Comment: Is there a way to have the inner text read, and then have a label read by the screen reader? I have something dynamic occurring while the user types - so would like to indicate both to them: the state of the dynamic element, and the input. Currently, the screen reader interrupts itself, and you don't hear the dynamic content as you should.